# Uneven load distribution in Tomcat application servers proxy balanced in front end Apache httpd web server

Tags: apache, tomcat

I am using 6 Apache httpd 2.2.15 which are forwarding requests to the Tomcat application servers (version: 7.0.41). Using mod_proxy, all the application servers are balanced with proxy balancers. Below is the similar configuration of apache httpd.conf:

```
##Proxy Balancers for use by all Virtual Hosts
<Proxy balancer://FrontEnd>
   BalancerMember ajp://APP01.abcd.com:8009 route=APP01 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP02.abcd.com:8009 route=APP02 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP03.abcd.com:8009 route=APP03 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP04.abcd.com:8009 route=APP04 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP05.abcd.com:8009 route=APP05 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP06.abcd.com:8009 route=APP06 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP07.abcd.com:8009 route=APP07 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP08.abcd.com:8009 route=APP08 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP09.abcd.com:8009 route=APP09 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP10.abcd.com:8009 route=APP10 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP11.abcd.com:8009 route=APP11 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP12.abcd.com:8009 route=APP12 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP13.abcd.com:8009 route=APP13 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP14.abcd.com:8009 route=APP14 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP15.abcd.com:8009 route=APP15 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP16.abcd.com:8009 route=APP16 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP21.abcd.com:8009 route=APP21 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP22.abcd.com:8009 route=APP22 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP23.abcd.com:8009 route=APP23 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP24.abcd.com:8009 route=APP24 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp://APP25.abcd.com:8009 route=APP25 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP26.abcd.com:8009 route=APP26 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP27.abcd.com:8009 route=APP27 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
   BalancerMember ajp:// APP28.abcd.com:8009 route=APP28 timeout=120 ttl=600 keepalive=On
    ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID
</Proxy>
```

I am facing the uneven load distribution issue among the application servers when I check it from the Apache webserver balancer-manager. Infact, the top 13 app servers (app01 to app13, assume batch1) are getting almost equal load and the remaining app servers (app14 to app16 and app21 to app28, assume batch2) are getting equal load. The batch1 app servers have almost 3 times more load than the batch2 app servers.

I also tried to diagnose if any network issue might be causing the problem. So, tried the traceroute command for the diagnosis and found almost similar patterns with 30 hops for both the batch servers (batch1 as well as batch2).

I am unable to figure out, what the issue is? Can anyone please help me out.
Any help, really appreciated.

Comment: Either the loadbalancer _thinks_ those two servers are less busy or they really _are_. Do they use faster hardware or a different configuration ? Did you define any stickyness that might lead to more connections being directed to the same server ? But there might be a better place on Stack Exchange to ask such questions.

Comment: The hardware and the configuration are same. There is no stickyness defined in the web servers. Only, the stickysession is enabled to capture out the JSESSIONID for one particular request going to the application server. Thanks Marged.

Comment: I tried with changing the lbmethod as "bytraffic" and reloaded the server. After the reload, the load in each app servers was evenly distributed. But after sometime again the load gets uneven,i.e, say Batch-1 taking almost 80% load and the remaining(20%) by Batch-2. The same thing happens when the lbmethod is "byrequests" by default. Also, I had removed the APP21-APP28 (Batch-2 contains only APP14-APP16 now) from the proxy balancers, but still the problem persists. Could anyone help please.

Comment: **restarting the web servers gracefully** solved the issue. I believe reloading the web servers (to avoid any downtime) after the changes doesn't close all the connections and again open it. This could be the reason of uneven load balancing among the app servers. Anyway Thanks :) @Marged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**restarting the web servers gracefully** solved the issue. Reloading the web servers (to avoid any downtime) after the changes doesn't close all the connections and again open it at the time of start. This creates a conjunction. I believe this could be the reason of uneven load balancing among the app servers. Anyway Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you were not using bybusyness method, then it makes sense that only after graceful restart the load was even. Based on the description in
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html, the request or traffic is based on historical values so that can be uneven if for example you had half of your app servers offline for a while, then you brought them up, those servers that just came up would probably need to catch up with traffic and apache would send the requests there. On the other side, bybusyness algorithm is looking at how busy the workers currently are, you should try that and see if you need to gracefully restart.